# How best to promote the DevOps site?

Tags: discussion

I've started promoting this site [via LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/devops-stack-exchange-beta-one-month-richard-slater) by writing a pulse post, please do feel free to re-use the words, images and text anywhere you feel it would benefit from it.

How else should we promote the site? I am cognizant that we need to strike a balance between visible and annoying so I am resisting cross posting too much at this stage.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Banner]

On September 15th, 2008 StackOverflow hit the Internet; created by Joel Spolsky and Jeff Atwood to be the Software Developer's answer to the inherently closed incumbent Q&A sites. Eight and a half years later and the site is ranked in the top 50 most visited sites in the world and is the defacto standard for getting answers to questions, spawning many more sites in the StackExchange network.

[image: StackExchange]

The StackExchange network is an extension of the StackOverflow concept, allowing for new sites modelled after StackOverflow to be proposed, taken into private and public beta with the goal of eventually becoming a fully fledged part of the network.

A little over a month ago now a new site entered private beta, it's based on a topic close to my heart, specifically DevOps. You could be forgiven for thinking that DevOps questions should appear on StackOverflow or the sister site ServerFault, however many questions about Culture, Tools, Transformation and Techniques have been closed because they are off-topic - the new DevOps StackExchange Beta is the place that these questions can be asked and answered freely, by example we have had these questions posted in the last 30 days:

- [What is a "Walking Skeleton"?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/712/397)
- [How to explain DevOps to a non-techy manager?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/643/397)
- [Who is this Chaos Monkey and why did he crash my server?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/609/397)
- [What is SecOps?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/686/397)
- [Which university has a good postgraduate DevOps programme?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/599/397)

### Who is involved?

There is a small core of five to six users who are using the site on a regular basis and another thirty or so whom we see on a semi-regular basis. This is where we need your help - we need more question, more answers, more comments and more votes. We have an opportunity here to build a community that espouses the principles of the DevOps community whilst gathering answers to the questions we have about DevOps.

### How do I get involved?

Signing up to any StackExchange site is easy, just head over to the site and click the Sign In button at the top. Do you already have a question in mind, great, ask away! Do you have experience in DevOps, I am sure you do, take a look at the unanswered questions and jump right in.

I personally am excited by this proposal, looking forward to seeing you on the site and answering your questions very soon.

Comment: Does it answer your question or is it a complement to it ? I've the feeling it should be within the question itself.

Comment: It's **an** answer IMHO, I've put it out there to 1) licence it as CC and 2) allow you all to edit it.  Let me know when you do edit it and I will update the original article.

Comment: In mine (humble opinion), it's a shareable post example, the one linked in your question. But not an answer to "How best to promote the DevOps site?" nor "How else should we promote the site?". Hence why I think it should be in the question, with the link from the question above it to show it in situation. But that's just my 2cts